# Change NLS Character set parameters on Oracle 11g XE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-xe

I am using Oracle 11g Express Edition. Currently when I check NLS character set parameter using `SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters;` it gives the default values:

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET: AL32UTF8
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET: AL16UTF16
```

I want to set both these parameters to UTF8. How can I do so? I have just installed Oracle 11g XE, so there is not data except those required by Oracle itself.

Comment: command: `SELECT * FROM SYS.nls_database_parameter;` doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me where an application was checking for **`UTF8 rather than AL32UTF8`** .

```
SQL> shutdown immediate;

SQL> startup restrict

SQL> select name from v$database;

SQL> ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET INTERNAL_USE UTF8 ;

SQL> select value from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS 
     where parameter=’NLS_CHARACTERSET’;

SQL> shutdown immediate;

SQL> startup
```

Comment: EM login page - corrupted

Comment: Your answer was very helpful for me. I was trying to change default charset in dockerized Oracle XE. It is possible if sequence of commands `SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE; STARTUP RESTRICT; ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET INTERNAL_USE EE8ISO8859P2; SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE; STARTUP;` is inserted before this line: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/25dae6127a6cd1aa233e2ee98db5f4da914f6bf8/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/11.2.0.2/runOracle.sh#L142

Answer (score 3):

<s>Maybe this works: `alter database character set UTF8;`</s> --> Not supported anymore on Oracle 10.1 or later.

However, are you really sure to change it? `AL32UTF8` **is** UTF-8, actually.

On Oracle you have also a character set called `UTF8`, this is a kind of misnomer and means Character set [CESU-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8). As far as I know this is like "UTF-8 as of Unicode version 3 from 1999". As long as you use Unicode characters less than 65535 (Basic Multilingual Plane) `AL32UTF8` and `UTF8` are identical.

Note, this command works only if the new character set is a strict superset of old character set. I.e. you can change from `US7ASCII` to `AL32UTF8` or `WE8ISO8859P1` but you cannot change from `WE8ISO8859P1` to `AL32UTF8`.

Comment: I've tried applying mentioned command, it gives following error.

`SQL Error: ORA-12712: new character set must be a superset of old character set`

I am agree that Characterset should not be changed. But the application I am installing require `NLS_CHARACTERSET` and `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` set to `UTF8`.

Comment: I doupt that any application may have such a requirement - unless it uses some **very** special characters.

Comment: I can understand that. Actually I am not much aware about Oracle database. If you say that if `AL32UTF8` is `UTF8` that is clear as the name suggest, but for `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` it is having value as `AL16UTF16`, so it does means that it is `UTF16` Characterset.

How to change that parameter to UTF8?

Comment: Yes, it means UTF-16. `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` is used for datatype `NVARCHAR2`, resp `NCHAR`. It was useful in earlier times before Unicode was invented. Today there is actually no reason anymore to use one of these datatypes.

Comment: Having NLS_CHARACTERSET set to AL32UTF8 is not the same as UTF8. For example: you cannot connect into AL32UTF8 database with old client (like Oracle Forms 6 runtime), while you can connect to UTF8 database. .

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the [character set](https://orahow.com/find-character-set-using-nls_database_parameters/) once you set installation. If you want to change then there is long procedure for which you need to raise SR with Oracle.

Answer (score -3):

```
SQL> shutdown immediate;

SQL> startup restrict

SQL> select name from v$database;

SQL> ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET INTERNAL_USE WE8MSWIN1252 ;

SQL> select value from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS where parameter=’NLS_CHARACTERSET’;

SQL> shutdown immediate;

SQL> startup

SQL> select value from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS where parameter=’NLS_CHARACTERSET’;
```

Comment: It is not recommended at all for the production DB.  It will corrupt database and will be beyond recovery,