# How can I create an Oracle database in docker, using UTF8 as national character set?

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle18c

I have created a docker container, containing an Oracle 18 XE instance with a container database and a pluggable database. The application I want to test with this pluggable database requires the database to have national character set UTF8. I can not change this, it is just a requirement.

The (empty) database is created and up and running. The character set however is AL16UTF16. I tried several options to change the national character set of both the container database and the pluggable database, all without success.

The procedure I followed, is described [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/deliver-oracle-database-18c-express-edition-in-containers). The docker images I downloaded from [github](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images), and the installer for Oracle 18c Express Edition from [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/xe-downloads.html).

I tried to add the parameter to the docker run command:
`-e ORACLE_NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET=UTF8`, without success.

Before creating the docker image, I tried adding the setting `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET=UTF8` to the configuration file `oracle-xe-18c.conf`, without success.

I tried the instructions from [this site](https://www.stechies.com/change-national-character-set-oracle-database-utf8/), without success. While the database is empty, trying to change the national character set results in the message `ORA-12717: Cannot issue ALTER DATABASE NATIONAL CHARACTER SET when NCLOB, NCHAR or NVARCHAR2 data exists`. I checked columns affected by the change of national character set with `select owner, table_name, column_name from dba_tab_columns where (data_type = 'NCHAR' or data_type = 'NVARCHAR2' or data_type = 'NCLOB') and owner != 'SYS' and owner != 'SYSTEM';`, and then a `select *` on all columns found. They all contained no data.

How can I create an Oracle database in docker, using the national character set UTF8?

Comment: Check this [link](https://sujeetdba.blogspot.com/2017/06/changing-national-character-set.html) same as you tried with instructions except it involves updating properties

Answer (score 0):

Your version of Oracle is 18 which [directly supports](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/25dae6127a6cd1aa233e2ee98db5f4da914f6bf8/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/18.4.0/runOracle.sh#L88) setting default charset via environment variable. I didn't try it but I guess just calling `docker run -e ORACLE_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8 ...` could be sufficient.

I solved this problem on 11g using `ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET INTERNAL_USE ...`. This command must be run on db in restricted mode (see [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28291640/653539), my application on docker scripts is in comment, it should be applicable to Oracle 18 too).

Comment: I solved it by changing the line `nationalCharacterSet=AL16UTF16` in `docker-images\OracleDatabase\SingleInstance\dockerfiles\19.3.0\dbca.rsp.tmpl` into `nationalCharacterSet=UTF8`. And yes, I am using Oravcle 19 now.